# Java: Abstract class

Tags: java, oop, constructor, abstract

Ok so I have something to be done for my assignment that is not very clear to me.
The program should be something of a simplified smartphone platform. There is one abstract class called Device, it is extended by two subclasses Actor and Sensor.

Now the unclear thing asked is that Actor should contain a constructor with two protected attributes: long *id* and String *description*.These two attributes should be able to fetch the values from the outside via getters and setters. I was thinking of initializing it through the mother class (Device) but that seems impossible, or does it?

The other thing is the Sensor subclass which should contain a protected long *value* which would store values gathered from the sensors and should be accessible through getValue. These sensors would be simulated on every call for getValue with "new java.util.Random().nextLong();" and stored to *value* and returned (classic return value).

Any help and advice/explanations will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The super class can only access attributes, which are defined within the super class. With this said, you need to set the attributes of `Actor` within its own constructor (if `Device` does not have the attributes `id` and `description`).
As for the Getter of `Sensor`: for what you are writing, it is straight forward: upon calling `getValue()`, the `Sensor` object generates a new `long` via `Random`, stores the random value in `value` and returns `value`.

Comment: And is there a way I can initialize a constructor inside the Actor class but referring to Device object, the variables needed are initialized in the Device class

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correctly, but you can call the superclass's constructor with `super(...)`.